# Adding password to website using HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: python, flask

So I'm trying to add a password to this application : https://github.com/RocketMap/RocketMap . After some time I found out that the file where main site is rendered(render template) is located at /pogo/app.py so I tried to add everything although im having trouble with app.Flask because the application itself isn't launched by app.py but by runserver.py. Can someone help me? :D
Here's my changed code(I cut irrevelant part and here's original: https://github.com/RocketMap/RocketMap/blob/develop/pogom/app.py):

```
  import flask
  from flask import Flask
  from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth



app = flask.Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
users = {
"john": "hello",
"susan": "bye"
}





class Pogom(Flask):

def __init__(self, import_name, **kwargs):
    super(Pogom, self).__init__(import_name, **kwargs)
    compress.init_app(self)

    args = get_args()
```

---

```
    self.route("/", methods=['POST','GET'])(self.fullmap)
```

---

```
@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None
```

---

```
@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def fullmap(self):
    self.heartbeat[0] = now()
    args = get_args()
```

Comment: Or maybe someone knows other way to implement password to this site?

Comment: Take a look [hee](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/)

Comment: Never mind i fixed it and I don't know how :D Thank you